# Selecting items that have same values in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a conundrum; not sure why -- is it because this late, or I am just stuck. My goal is to create a filter on the webpage, so I am trying to figure this out.

I have a list of products that I store with filters in the reference table `product_filter`.

The structure:

```
id | product_id | filter1_id | filter2_id
1  |    1       | 2          |     1   <---
2  |    1       | 4          |     3
3  |    1       | 5          |     1
4  |    2       | 2          |     1   <---
5  |    2       | 3          |     1
6  |    3       | 2          |     1   <---
7  |    3       | 3          |     4
```

I need to submit a list of products (for example 1,2,3) and get only those filter combinations, that are the same for all selected product id's. So the result needs to be

```
filter1_id | filter2_id
     2     |     1
```

My problem is that my products might vary and I can't do a ton of self inner joins... so I am stuck... Any advise?

Comment: try using `count(filter1_id)` > 1 in where clause ...

Comment: Andrew, any joy on a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach that you could try:

```
select filter1_id, filter2_id 
from product_filter
group by filter1_id, filter2_id
  having count(*)=(
    select count(distinct product_id) 
    from product_filter
  )
```

This will only return a list when a combination of filter1_id and filter2_id exists for *every* product_id. ([Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7e8/1)) Is that what you are after? Do you don't mention what should be returned if there isn't any combination that exists for all of the given product_id's - an empty result set?

It's not a self-join (or even a ton of them ;) ) but it will still be fairly expensive I imagine.